# Linux Kernel drivers for non I2C/SPI based sensors (for analog sensors)

Tags: kernel, linux-device-driver

I recently started learning IIO-subsystem and now quite comfortable with SPI / I2C based sensors within IIO subsystem (using Regmap APIs as well).

However, today I came across a potentiometer sensor : http://wiki.seeedstudio.com/Grove-Rotary_Angle_Sensor/

It exposes 4 pins as GND, VCC, NC and SIG. If I had to use this sensor with my raspberry Pi and only had to use Linux kernel, how would I be exposing the sensor data to the userspace?

Is there a category for such devices within IIO subsystem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read an analog voltage like that you need an ADC (analog-to-digital converter), and the Raspberry Pi does not have a built-in ADC. You can find any of a number of analog input hats for your Raspberry Pi, and they will typically contain a SPI chip with an ADC in it that can be accessed from userspace via Linux [spidev subsystem](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/spi/spidev) or some [higher level Python module](https://learn.adafruit.com/reading-a-analog-in-and-controlling-audio-volume-with-the-raspberry-pi/script).

There is ADC support in the IIO subsystem, you can load the relevant devicetree overlay like described here: https://jumpnowtek.com/rpi/Using-mcp3008-ADCs-with-Raspberry-Pis.html

Comment: Sorry I am little confused.  I have seen people using DS18B20 temperature sensors with Raspberry Pi and no ADC in between, and the sensor is neither SPI or I2C based. How does that sensor able to communicate? Which protocol it works on.

Comment: @InsaneCoder DS18B20 is a digital sensor which uses the [1wire protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1-Wire). It is easy to connect any number of them to a GPIO pin on a Raspberry Pi with little additional hardware (one or two resistors), and there is a kernel driver to talk to them and retrieve temperature samples.

Comment: So can this gpio pin read the range of temperatures (say [0-100]), which is non-digital? What is the driver called?

Comment: The driver is called w1-gpio. There are many tutorials on the Internet that can give you an idea of how it works, for example this one: http://www.circuitbasics.com/raspberry-pi-ds18b20-temperature-sensor-tutorial/